# RazorEngine throw a NotSupportedException when compiling template in Azure Function

Tags: azure, caching, azure-functions, razorengine

I must compile a razor view in an azure function to send an email, but something goes wrong. I obtain the a `NotSupportedException` error: `The given path's format is not supported.`

Here my code:

```
private IRazorEngineService _engine;

public MyCtor(bool isTestEnvironment)
{
    TemplateServiceConfiguration configuration = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
    configuration.Debug = isTestEnvironment;

    this._engine = RazorEngineService.Create(configuration);
}

public string GetHtmlEmailBody(string templateFileName, object emailData, string layoutFileName)
{
    //Get data type of email data
    Type emailDataType = emailData.GetType();

    string layoutFullFileName = Path.Combine(this._layoutPath, layoutFileName);
    string layoutContentString = File.ReadAllText(layoutFullFileName);
    var layout = new LoadedTemplateSource(layoutContentString, layoutFullFileName);

    this._engine.AddTemplate("layoutName", layout);

    string templateFullFileName = Path.Combine(this._templatePath, templateFileName);
    string templateContentString = File.ReadAllText(templateFullFileName);
    var template = new LoadedTemplateSource(templateContentString, templateFullFileName);

    this._engine.AddTemplate("templateName", template);

    this._engine.Compile("templateName"); //<-- Here I get the exception
    string htmlEmailBody = this._engine.Run("templateName", emailDataType, emailData);

    return htmlEmailBody;
}
```

Paths are similar to `D:\\...\\Emails\\Templates`.. I am testing locally and it does not work... I have googled and it seems that Azure Functions have some limitations in caching and in file system management, but it is not clear how can  I solve the problem.
I think I have same problem this person has written [here](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/496)

Any idea how can I solve it? There is something wrong in what I am doing?

I am using RazorEngine 3.10.0
Thank you

Comment: This sounds more like a question for the RazorEngine folks, but it would be interesting to know the exact path that's causing errors for you.

Comment: The path is `{ProjectDir}Emails\Templates\_MyTemplate.v1.cshtml`... I am sure the path is correct because when I instanciate a new `LoadedTemplateSource`, the property `Template` is correctly valorized with the HTML of the template

Comment: Onestly I think is a problema abuot caching...

Answer (score 3):

I have found the problem, downloading the code and doing reverse engineering.
Problem was inside the `UseCurrentAssembliesReferenceResolver` class, in the `GetReferences` method... here the code that throws the exception:

```
return CompilerServicesUtility
           .GetLoadedAssemblies()
           .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic && File.Exists(a.Location) && !a.Location.Contains(CompilerServiceBase.DynamicTemplateNamespace))
           .GroupBy(a => a.GetName().Name).Select(grp => grp.First(y => y.GetName().Version == grp.Max(x => x.GetName().Version))) // only select distinct assemblies based on FullName to avoid loading duplicate assemblies
           .Select(a => CompilerReference.From(a))
           .Concat(includeAssemblies ?? Enumerable.Empty<CompilerReference>());
```

Exactly the statements that throw the exception are `File.Exists(a.Location) && !a.Location.Contains(CompilerServiceBase.DynamicTemplateNamespace))`. The problem is that in Azure function some assemblies are protected, so no information can be retrieved about them... (surely I must study about azure functions)...

At the moment I solved writing a custom ReferenceResolver. I copied exactly the same code from the `UseCurrentAssembliesReferenceResolver` and I changed just the `Where` conditions..

So

```
.Where(a => !a.IsDynamic && File.Exists(a.Location) && !a.Location.Contains(CompilerServiceBase.DynamicTemplateNamespace))
```

became

```
.Where(a => !a.IsDynamic && !a.FullName.Contains("Version=0.0.0.0") && File.Exists(a.Location) && !a.Location.Contains("CompiledRazorTemplates.Dynamic"))
```

I am almost sure that it is not the best way to solve the problem... but now I solved it, and after two days my work is blocked I need to go on... I hope this can help someone...